# Recently I meet Linkedin API errors - Failed to obtain OAuth 2.0 access token

Tags: api, oauth, linkedin-api

Sometimes I get error messages from Linkedin API after my application is trying to access it by authentication call. Anyone know what's is the reason for that and how to solve this?

```
ERROR: Error occured while trying to authenticate: Failed to obtain OAuth 2.0 access token from  https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken!
HTTP status: 999, message: <html>\n<head>\n 
<script type="text/javascript">\n window.onload = function()\n {\n 
var cookies = document.cookie.split('; '); \n for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)\n {\n var fields = cookies[i].split('='); \n if (fields.length == 2)\n 
{\n var name = fields[0].replace(/\s/g, ''); \n
if (name == 'denial-reason-code')\n {\n 
document.getElementById('denialReasonCodes').textContent = fields[1]; \n }\n 
if (name == 'denial-client-ip')\n {\n document.getElementById('denialIp').textContent = fields[1]; \n }\n }\n }\n
document.getElementById('denialUrl').textContent = document.location; \n
document.getElementById('denialTime').textContent = (new Date()).toString(); \n
```